# Total Count of TBD under a parent in Json Data in JavaScript/Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

The below JSON Data Has EmployeeNumber With TBD and Number I would need only TBD count form the JSON and to be attached the parent

```
var myJson={
"Name": "Sam",
"EmployeeNumber": "002",
 "IsManager":"True",
 "children": [{
        "Name": "Ravi",
       "EmployeeNumber": "0008",
         "IsManager":"True",
        "children": [{
                "Name": "Krishna",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
            }, {
                "Name": "diwakar",
                "EmployeeNumber": "007"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Dillep",
                "EmployeeNumber": "009"
            },
            {
                "Name": "David",
                "EmployeeNumber": "009"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Nicholes",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Hari",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Rahul",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Kiran",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    }, {
        "Name": "Kumar",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    },
    {
        "Name": "AJAy",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    }
]
```

}

From the above JSON, I Would like to have Total Count of TBD and add the count to Parent Name: **Sam**=4TBD/0FTE and The children TBD Count to **Ravi** =3TBD/3FTE and if IS Manager is True

Expected Output:

```
var myJson={
"Name": "Sam",
"EmployeeNumber": "002",
"IsManager": "Ture",
"Count": "4TBD/0FTE",
"children": [{
        "Name": "Ravi",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "IsManager": "Ture",
        "Count": "3TBD/3FTE",
        "children": [{
                "Name": "Krishna",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
            }, {
                "Name": "diwakar",
                "EmployeeNumber": "007"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Dillep",
                "EmployeeNumber": "009"
            },
            {
                "Name": "David",
                "EmployeeNumber": "009"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Nicholes",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Hari",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Rahul",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Kiran",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    }, {
        "Name": "Kumar",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    },
    {
        "Name": "AJAy",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    }
]
```

}

I tried with below one

```
    var annCtr=[];
    var annFtr=[];
    arr.forEach(function(myJSON) {
    var ctr=[];
    var ftr=[];
     if (myJSON.EmployeeNumber == "TBD") {
        annCtr.push(myJSON.EmployeeNumber);
        ctr.push(myJSON.EmployeeNumber);
       }
    else
    {
    annFtr.push(myJSON.EmployeeNumber);
    ftr.push(myJSON.EmployeeNumber);
    //console.log("FTR :"+myJSON.EmployeeNumber+" Name "+myJSON.Name);
    }
//console.log("Length CTRCT for each loop: "+ctr.length);
//console.log("Length FTE for each loop: "+ftr.length);
})
function children(myJSON) {
  return myJSON.children;
  console.log(d.children);
}
console.log("Total Length FTE for : "+annFtr.length);
console.log("Total Length CTRCT for: "+annCtr.length);
console.log('//////////////////////////////////////////');
```

Thanks in Advance for all the help

Comment: do you only want to total number of TBD? cause i can do it with reduce + recursion. but you have FTE and CTRCT which idk what they are

Comment: I need TBD and FTE Both TBD Is nothing but (CTRCT)

Comment: you should really explain what they mean

Comment: Referring  to JSON above: TBD means Number of Contract Employees under a Parent and Which has Number  Is FTES                                            
I need the total count of Contractors and FTE'S under each  parent

Comment: If I understand right, Your use case is confusing. The input has 5 FTE's first. in the expected it says 4. Whats happening there?

Comment: For the parent: sam   I would count Rahul, Kiran, Kumar,Ajay
Which contains all TBD's(4) 4TBD/0FTE
For Parent: Ravi I would count Krishna,diwakar,Dilip, David, Nicholes, Hari
Which Contains 3TBD/3FTE

Comment: Please find the code snippet in the answer I have below. Hope that helps!
Also, I think you are missing to count the manager (Ravi) who reports to Sam. So Sam would have 4TBD/1FTE

Comment: Yeah probably I was missing to count Ravi as well But how do I get count under Ravi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the below snippet helps what you wanted.

```js
var myJson={
"Name": "Sam",
"EmployeeNumber": "002",
 "IsManager":"True",
 "children": [{
        "Name": "Ravi",
       "EmployeeNumber": "0008",
         "IsManager":"True",
        "children": [{
                "Name": "Krishna",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
            }, {
                "Name": "diwakar",
                "EmployeeNumber": "007"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Dillep",
                "EmployeeNumber": "009"
            },
            {
                "Name": "David",
                "EmployeeNumber": "009"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Nicholes",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Hari",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Rahul",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Kiran",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    }, {
        "Name": "Kumar",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    },
    {
        "Name": "AJAy",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD"
    }
]
}

function getReporteeCount(employee) {
employee.count = employee.children.reduce( (result,child) => {
if(child.IsManager)
  getReporteeCount(child);
if (child.EmployeeNumber === 'TBD')
result.TBDCount = result.TBDCount + 1;
else 
result.FTECount = result.FTECount + 1;

return result}, {FTECount:0 , TBDCount:0})
}

getReporteeCount(myJson)

console.log(myJson)
```

Comment: This is the Output i am getting after running the above code in javascript/nodejs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzuRD.png

Comment: I believe that is the expected output.

Comment: But When I check with run code snippet it is giving right output in StackOverflow

Comment: how the stackoverflow compiler output vs node is different? If you can explain on that, I would be able to help you more.

Comment: I am using node v8.9.4 and I tried online node  compiler but everywhere the o/p is same  I am not sure how the  StackOverflow compiler output is different from what i am getting FYI(Nodejs Compiler i tried):https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php

Comment: Are you mentioning count: Object object as the difference?

Comment: Yes I am referring to that  In StackOverflow i see data under Ravi in output and count

Comment: It is an parsed JSON. You can directly access the objects by properties. If you want to see the JSON string, you will need to stringify it. Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson))` instead of `console.log(myJson)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, CRayen