# Total children count in nested json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the total employee count under a manager and trying to add it If IsManager=True from the below nested JSON

```
[{
"name": "Wendeline",
"IsManager": "TRUE",
"children": [{
    "name": "Goraud",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 706997,
    "children": [{
        "name": "Mersey",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 102752,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Elli",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 742047,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Hans",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Bald",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 741064,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Truda",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 739162,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Matty",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 717067,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Ola",
        "IsManager": "TRUE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 713122,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Frankie",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Quint",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 705616,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Georgi",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 733001,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Danie",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 742962,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Judon",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 750620,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Nellie",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 101490,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Marji",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 705660,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Adelaida",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Bing",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 745205,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Odilia",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 718622,
            "children": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Bernardina",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 726710,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Myca",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 726163,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Husain",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 728267,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Cristie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 750267,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Nikolai",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "James",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Ashbey",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 744719,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Flss",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 746709,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Felisha",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 739945,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Zelig",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Jakob",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Cointon",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
}, {
    "name": "Jo",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 716884,
    "children": [{
        "name": "Sylvia",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 744160,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Vicki",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 735637,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Blanche",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 729407,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Mirabelle",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 731551,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Floria",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 727255,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Flossie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Anny",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Hyatt",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Juli",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 740132,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Isacco",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 742246,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Fleurette",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 742205,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Dicky",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 742736,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Wini",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 741836,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Elden",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 743234,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Marjie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 740196,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Vanna",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 738053,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Emilio",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 751901,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Enrique",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Lilas",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Elita",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Hyacintha",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Markus",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Calhoun",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Melisande",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 748847,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Haroun",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Niles",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Adorne",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 724804,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Dianne",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 724863,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Faye",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 732329,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Tabina",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 724910,
        "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Spike",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 732941,
    "children": [{
        "name": "Reta",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Cirillo",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Berty",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 726527,
    "children": [{
        "name": "Gerrie",
        "IsManager": "TRUE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 727939,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Kelci",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 739483,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Alexandros",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 723369,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Loreen",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 746432,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Cortie",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Keven",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 723060,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Shanie",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 707562,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Hatti",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Tammi",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 717763,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Blondell",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 731167,
            "children": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Bellina",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 731162,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Constancia",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Dieter",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 725942,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Illa",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 733953,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Roley",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Talbot",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Theodora",
        "IsManager": "TRUE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 721734,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Ebeneser",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 741729,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Allie",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Benita",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Elmira",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Dene",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 739572,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Hamil",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 731393,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Fitzgerald",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 710334,
            "children": [{
                "name": "Leon",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Mignon",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Constantina",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 744831,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Alysa",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 736292,
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Garrik",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
}, {
    "name": "Onofredo",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
}, {
    "name": "Josefa",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
}, {
    "name": "Nan",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
}, {
    "name": "Birgit",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
}, {
    "name": "Ashlan",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
}, {
    "name": "Rod",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 726043,
    "children": [{
        "name": "Lorie",
        "IsManager": "TRUE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 711520,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Norris",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 736426,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Josefa",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 728365,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Carma",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 751153,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Rozelle",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 738418,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Tine",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 721367,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Ransom",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Hildagarde",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Grant",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 712948,
            "children": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Karilynn",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 102152,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Tine",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 717285,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Lenna",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 707659,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "Fanni",
        "IsManager": "TRUE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 102936,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Nani",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 726746,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Jethro",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 744442,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Olenka",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Morena",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Susana",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Hammad",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "Erwin",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 711550,
            "children": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Petr",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
       }]
   }]
  }]
```

I tried this link: [Headcount under nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318756/headcount-under-nested-json)

But this is for direct count.I need the total children count.
 I am looking for this output as below

If IsManager=True add this TotalCount as a key Value to parent

"Key(TotalCount)":"TotalChildrencount/TotalTBDCount/TotalEmployeeCount(Only who has employee number)"

Example:

{
"name":"Wendeline",
"IsManager": "TRUE",
"count":"131/44TBD/87FTE"
}

Like Wendeline all those who are having 'IsManager:True' should show total children Count/Total TBD/Total FTE

Any Help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: And since you already have a solution for a very similar question, it should be pretty straightforward for you to try to modify it for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [{
  "name": "Wendeline",
  "IsManager": "TRUE",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Goraud",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 706997,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Mersey",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 102752,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Elli",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 742047,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Hans",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Bald",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 741064,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Truda",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 739162,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Matty",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 717067,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Ola",
      "IsManager": "TRUE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 713122,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Frankie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Quint",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 705616,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Georgi",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 733001,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Danie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 742962,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Judon",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 750620,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Nellie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 101490,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Marji",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 705660,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Adelaida",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Bing",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 745205,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Odilia",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 718622,
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Bernardina",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 726710,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Myca",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 726163,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Husain",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 728267,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Cristie",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 750267,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Nikolai",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "James",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Ashbey",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 744719,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Flss",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 746709,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Felisha",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 739945,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Zelig",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Jakob",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Cointon",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Jo",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 716884,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Sylvia",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 744160,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Vicki",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 735637,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Blanche",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 729407,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Mirabelle",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 731551,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Floria",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 727255,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Flossie",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Anny",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Hyatt",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Juli",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 740132,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Isacco",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 742246,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Fleurette",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 742205,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Dicky",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 742736,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Wini",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 741836,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Elden",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 743234,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Marjie",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 740196,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Vanna",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 738053,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Emilio",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 751901,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Enrique",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Lilas",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Elita",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Hyacintha",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Markus",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Calhoun",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Melisande",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 748847,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Haroun",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Niles",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Adorne",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 724804,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Dianne",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 724863,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Faye",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 732329,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Tabina",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 724910,
      "children": []
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Spike",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 732941,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Reta",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Cirillo",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Berty",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 726527,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Gerrie",
      "IsManager": "TRUE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 727939,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Kelci",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 739483,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Alexandros",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 723369,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Loreen",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 746432,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Cortie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Keven",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 723060,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Shanie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 707562,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Hatti",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Tammi",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 717763,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Blondell",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 731167,
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Bellina",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 731162,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Constancia",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Dieter",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 725942,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Illa",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 733953,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Roley",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Talbot",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Theodora",
      "IsManager": "TRUE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 721734,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Ebeneser",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 741729,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Allie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Benita",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Elmira",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Dene",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 739572,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Hamil",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 731393,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Fitzgerald",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 710334,
        "children": [{
          "name": "Leon",
          "IsManager": "FALSE",
          "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
          "children": []
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Mignon",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Constantina",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 744831,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Alysa",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 736292,
        "children": []
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Garrik",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Onofredo",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Josefa",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Nan",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Birgit",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Ashlan",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Rod",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 726043,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Lorie",
      "IsManager": "TRUE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 711520,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Norris",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 736426,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Josefa",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 728365,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Carma",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 751153,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Rozelle",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 738418,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Tine",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 721367,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Ransom",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Hildagarde",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Grant",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 712948,
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Karilynn",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 102152,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Tine",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 717285,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Lenna",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 707659,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Fanni",
      "IsManager": "TRUE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 102936,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Nani",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 726746,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Jethro",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 744442,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Olenka",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Morena",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Susana",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Hammad",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Erwin",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 711550,
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Petr",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }]
  }]
}];

function addCounts(users = []) {
  for (const user of users) {
    if (user.IsManager === 'TRUE') {
      const count = countChildren(user.children);
      user.count = `${count.total}/${count.tbd}TBD/${count.fte}FTE`;
    }
    
    user.children = addCounts(user.children);
  }

  return users;
}

function countChildren(children = []) {
  const count = {
    total: 0,
    fte: 0,
    tbd: 0
  };

  for (const child of children) {
    count.total++;

    if (child.EmployeeNumber === 'TBD') {
      count.tbd++;
    } else {
      count.fte++;
    }

    const childrenCount = countChildren(child.children);
    count.tbd += childrenCount.tbd;
    count.fte += childrenCount.fte;
    count.total += childrenCount.total;
  }

  return count;
}

console.log(addCounts(data));
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. But I have tried this and getting count only for 'Wendeline' who is at the topmost in this tree structure.But I need for all of them who has IsManager=true.For console.log(calculateCounts(data[0]).count); // If I am giving any number other than 0 it is throwing error.

Comment: @RRoy With a bit of generalization I added that. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Not sure if I understood your question the first time I answered it. Below is the updated answer.

Not sure the way you are structuring this data is the right way to do this. However, here is a recursive function that I built that will accomplish what you are trying to do.

```js
let data = [
  {
    "name": "Wendeline",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Goraud",
        "IsManager": "TRUE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 706997,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Mersey",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 102752,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Elli",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 742047,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Hans",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Bald",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 741064,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Truda",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 739162,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Matty",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 717067,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Ola",
            "IsManager": "TRUE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 713122,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Frankie",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Quint",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 705616,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Georgi",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 733001,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Danie",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 742962,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Judon",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 750620,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Nellie",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 101490,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Marji",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 705660,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Adelaida",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Bing",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 745205,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Odilia",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 718622,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Bernardina",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 726710,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Myca",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 726163,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Husain",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 728267,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Cristie",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 750267,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Nikolai",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "James",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Ashbey",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 744719,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Flss",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 746709,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Felisha",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 739945,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Zelig",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Jakob",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Cointon",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Jo",
        "IsManager": "TRUE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 716884,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Sylvia",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 744160,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Vicki",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 735637,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Blanche",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 729407,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Mirabelle",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 731551,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Floria",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 727255,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Flossie",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Anny",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Hyatt",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Juli",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 740132,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Isacco",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 742246,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Fleurette",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 742205,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Dicky",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 742736,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Wini",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 741836,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Elden",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 743234,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Marjie",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 740196,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Vanna",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 738053,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Emilio",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 751901,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Enrique",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Lilas",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Elita",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Hyacintha",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Markus",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Calhoun",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Melisande",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 748847,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Haroun",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Niles",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Adorne",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 724804,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Dianne",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 724863,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Faye",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 732329,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Tabina",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 724910,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Spike",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 732941,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Reta",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Cirillo",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Berty",
        "IsManager": "TRUE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 726527,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Gerrie",
            "IsManager": "TRUE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 727939,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Kelci",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 739483,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Alexandros",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 723369,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Loreen",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 746432,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Cortie",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Keven",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 723060,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Shanie",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 707562,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Hatti",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Tammi",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 717763,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Blondell",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 731167,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Bellina",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 731162,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Constancia",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Dieter",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 725942,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Illa",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 733953,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Roley",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Talbot",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Theodora",
            "IsManager": "TRUE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 721734,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Ebeneser",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 741729,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Allie",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Benita",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Elmira",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Dene",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 739572,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Hamil",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 731393,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Fitzgerald",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 710334,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "Leon",
                    "IsManager": "FALSE",
                    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                    "children": []
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "Mignon",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Constantina",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 744831,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Alysa",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 736292,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Garrik",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Onofredo",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Josefa",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Nan",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Birgit",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Ashlan",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Rod",
        "IsManager": "TRUE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 726043,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Lorie",
            "IsManager": "TRUE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 711520,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Norris",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 736426,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Josefa",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 728365,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Carma",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 751153,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Rozelle",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 738418,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Tine",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 721367,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Ransom",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Hildagarde",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Grant",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 712948,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Karilynn",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 102152,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Tine",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 717285,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Lenna",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 707659,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Fanni",
            "IsManager": "TRUE",
            "EmployeeNumber": 102936,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Nani",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 726746,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Jethro",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 744442,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Olenka",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Morena",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Susana",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Hammad",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Erwin",
                "IsManager": "FALSE",
                "EmployeeNumber": 711550,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Petr",
            "IsManager": "FALSE",
            "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

generateEmployeeCounts = (person, count) => {
  count ? count : count = { tbd: 0, fte: 0 };
  if (person && person.children) {
    person.children.forEach(child => {
      if (child.EmployeeNumber === "TBD") {
        count.tbd++;
      } else {
        count.fte++;
      }
      generateEmployeeCounts(child.children, count);
    });
  }
  return `Total: ${count.tbd + count.fte}/TBD: ${count.tbd}/FTE: ${count.fte}`;
}

detectManagers = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach(person => {
    if (person && person.children) {
      if (person.children.length > 0) {
        person.IsManager = true;
        detectManagers(person.children);
      } else {
        person.IsManager = false;
      }
      person.count = generateEmployeeCounts(person);
    }
  });
}

detectManagers(data);
console.log(data);
```

Again, I would advise you to restructure your data structure to not be so deeply nested. You could have a flat array of people. Each person could have a UID that gets applied to them. The children array under each person would be an array of UIDs that is used to track the manager relationship (children.) This would eliminate your deeply nested data structure.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure about what you're asking, but do you mean you want to find every manager including those in `children`?

Simply put your object in a variable:

```
var employees = [{
  "name": "Wendeline",
  "IsManager": "TRUE",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Goraud",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 706997,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Mersey",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 102752,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Elli",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 742047,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Hans",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Bald",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 741064,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Truda",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 739162,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Matty",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 717067,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Ola",
      "IsManager": "TRUE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 713122,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Frankie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Quint",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 705616,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Georgi",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 733001,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Danie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 742962,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Judon",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 750620,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Nellie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 101490,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Marji",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 705660,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Adelaida",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Bing",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 745205,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Odilia",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 718622,
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Bernardina",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 726710,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Myca",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 726163,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Husain",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 728267,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Cristie",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 750267,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Nikolai",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "James",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Ashbey",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 744719,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Flss",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 746709,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Felisha",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 739945,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Zelig",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Jakob",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Cointon",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Jo",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 716884,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Sylvia",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 744160,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Vicki",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 735637,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Blanche",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 729407,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Mirabelle",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 731551,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Floria",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 727255,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Flossie",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Anny",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Hyatt",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Juli",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 740132,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Isacco",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 742246,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Fleurette",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 742205,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Dicky",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 742736,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Wini",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 741836,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Elden",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 743234,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Marjie",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 740196,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Vanna",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 738053,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Emilio",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 751901,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Enrique",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Lilas",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Elita",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Hyacintha",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Markus",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Calhoun",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Melisande",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 748847,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Haroun",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Niles",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Adorne",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 724804,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Dianne",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 724863,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Faye",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 732329,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Tabina",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 724910,
      "children": []
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Spike",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 732941,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Reta",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Cirillo",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Berty",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 726527,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Gerrie",
      "IsManager": "TRUE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 727939,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Kelci",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 739483,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Alexandros",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 723369,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Loreen",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 746432,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Cortie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Keven",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 723060,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Shanie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 707562,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Hatti",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Tammi",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 717763,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Blondell",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 731167,
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Bellina",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 731162,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Constancia",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Dieter",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 725942,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Illa",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 733953,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Roley",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Talbot",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Theodora",
      "IsManager": "TRUE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 721734,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Ebeneser",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 741729,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Allie",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Benita",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Elmira",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Dene",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 739572,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Hamil",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 731393,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Fitzgerald",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 710334,
        "children": [{
          "name": "Leon",
          "IsManager": "FALSE",
          "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
          "children": []
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Mignon",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Constantina",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 744831,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Alysa",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 736292,
        "children": []
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Garrik",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Onofredo",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Josefa",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Nan",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Birgit",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Ashlan",
    "IsManager": "FALSE",
    "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Rod",
    "IsManager": "TRUE",
    "EmployeeNumber": 726043,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Lorie",
      "IsManager": "TRUE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 711520,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Norris",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 736426,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Josefa",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 728365,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Carma",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 751153,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Rozelle",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 738418,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Tine",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 721367,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Ransom",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Hildagarde",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Grant",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 712948,
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Karilynn",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 102152,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Tine",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 717285,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Lenna",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 707659,
      "children": []
    }, {
      "name": "Fanni",
      "IsManager": "TRUE",
      "EmployeeNumber": 102936,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Nani",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 726746,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Jethro",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 744442,
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Olenka",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Morena",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Susana",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Hammad",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Erwin",
        "IsManager": "FALSE",
        "EmployeeNumber": 711550,
        "children": []
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Petr",
      "IsManager": "FALSE",
      "EmployeeNumber": "TBD",
      "children": []
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Then use this code to find every manager:

```
var managers = [];

function findManagers(object) {
    for (var i in object) {
        if (object[i].IsManager === "TRUE") {
            managers.push(object[i]);

            if (object[i].children !== undefined) {
                findManagers(object[i].children);
            }
        }
    }
}

findManagers(employees);

console.log(managers);
```

Comment: Yes I wanted to find every manger Total HeadCount /FTE/TBD Count.Including those in children